# Are point sprites always perfect circles/squares?

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, glsl

I noticed that regardless of the shape (aspect ratio) of a texture, it will always draw as a perfect square, scaling unequally, when using it as a point sprite. I assume this is because points are, after all, circular.

If you wish to use point sprites on rectangular textures, is this possible using the point sprite mechanism, or would I need to just build quads with textures instead?

Or perhaps there is something that can be added to a shader to recognize and work with a rectangular texture? Currently mine are quite simple:

Vertex shader:

```
TextureCoordOut = TextureCoordinate;
gl_PointSize = 15.0;
```

Fragment:

```
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(Sampler, isSprite? gl_PointCoord: TextureCoordOut) * DestinationColor;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Points have only one size, which will be equally applied to the width and height..